# Getting MRPT to work

Tags: c++

I seem to miss a crucial point when trying to get started with MRPT. 
As a beginner I think the provided documentation / tutorials don't cover enough to get working.

I tried installing the binary for ubuntu which completed. Now trying to compile a project with codeblocks did not work. 
I wanted to add the include path for mrpt for compiler and lib path for linker.
Too bad I could not find a mrpt folder in /usr/lib.

After that I tried compiling from source. 
After figuring out that 1GB of Ram is not enough for MRPT to compile (swap exhausted too and system freezed). 
I managed to get it compiled and found the header files in /usr/local/include and libraries in /usr/local/libs.
But adding those paths to compiler / linker respectively did not help.
It seems that I'd have to add 3-layers of subfolders to my include statements to get my code to work. (Code I copied from mrpt site as an example)
I got codeblocks to not throw an error on my code by adding those 3 layers

```
    /mrpt/<package. someth like "base">/include/[... normal include ...]
```

just to get an error on my first include.

The error I'm talking about always states that my include could not be found.

I've tried different angles for 2 days now and am running out of options.
I hope you can give me a hint or something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you are getting such as bad experience... Part by part:

> I tried installing the binary for ubuntu 
>   ...
>   after figuring out that 1GB of Ram is not enough for MRPT to compile

After the `/usr/local/` path you mention, it seems to did a `sudo make install`, right? Unless you have some good reason, I strongly recommend undoing it (with `sudo make uninstall`) and installing the precompiled versions from this [PPA repository](http://www.mrpt.org/MRPT_in_GNU/Linux_repositories). They are updated on a ~monthly basis and avoids you having to build from sources.

> But adding those paths to compiler / linker respectively did not help. It seems that I'd have to add 3-layers of subfolders to my include

That is because MRPT uses a layout similar to OpenCV's, intended to be modular among the different MRPT libraries. It is strongly recommended to use:

- Makefile: [Instructions here](http://www.mrpt.org/tutorials/programming/first-steps/compiling_custom_applications_in_linux_with_a_makefile_and_pkg-config/)
- CMake (which can generate projects for CodeBlocks or, even better, QtCreator): [Instructions here](http://www.mrpt.org/Writing_applications_with_the_MRPT_C%2B%2B_Library)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I'll look into it.